# Iterating and modifying Firebase array causes undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

EDIT: it seems that value[i].extrainfoimage is only undefined within imageRef.child("-JlSvEAw......

I've read through the documentation twice so far and still haven't been able to figure this one out.

Basically I load some data from firebase and set it as an array. I iterate through that array and intend to replace some properties, as I iterate, with data I get from other places in my Firebase DB. However everytime I go to replace the properties I get

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'extrainfoimage' of undefined"

This is my code:

```
var questionsRef = new Firebase("https://XX.firebaseio.com/Questions");
var imageRef = new Firebase("https://XX.firebaseio.com/Images");

//get the first 6 items
var query = questionsRef.orderByChild('date_time_asked').limitToFirst(6);
//get them as a firebase array promise
$scope.questions = $firebaseArray(query);
//wait for it to load
$scope.questions.$loaded().then(function (value) {
//iterate through
for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    //check if there is data to be replaced
    if (value[i].extrainfoimage) {
           //if there is fetch it from firebase and replace
           imageRef.child("-JlSvEAwu5-WZJkOE_b/image").once("value",function(data){
                        value[i].extrainfoimage = data.val();
                    });
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: `$scope.questions.$loaded().then(function (value) {` This is returning `value` to be undefined. And you're trying to set `extrainfoimage` of undefined that's why you're getting that error.

Comment: No it's not. I wouldn't be entering my if statement if it was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly its becuase the last item in value doesn't have `extrainfoimage`. Because your set for `value[i].extrainfoimage` is async, it doesn't capture the correct `i` value, and therefore fails when it is executing.

Try to wrap it in a IIFE:

```
for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    //check if there is data to be replaced
    if (value[i].extrainfoimage) {
       (function(curr) {
           //if there is fetch it from firebase and replace
           imageRef.child("-JlSvEAwu5-WZJkOE_b/image").once("value",function(data){
                    value[curr].extrainfoimage = data.val();
           });
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Don't think I would have been able to figure this one out on my own. For some reason it wouldnt actually update the image until I switched to a different page and then went back to the page (I think this was more of an ionic issue than anything else) so I added

$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();

right after i changed the property and that seemed to fix it.